# Image in box table

Tags: html

I want put image in box, right before text I use this code but image goes up or down !

[image]

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="121">Download link</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://upload7.ir/up/icon-article-navy.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" class="dlboxicon" />[xfgiven_download]<a href="[xfvalue_download]"> [xfgiven_name] [xfvalue_name] [/xfgiven_name]</td>[/xfgiven_download] <a/>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you have to close *td* after a tag close.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Also, the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure has **tag closing mistakes**. Compare your structure with below structure.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="121">Download link</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctwrd.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" class="dlboxicon" />[xfgiven_download]
       <a href="[xfvalue_download]"> [xfgiven_name] [xfvalue_name] [/xfgiven_name][/xfgiven_download] </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the style "float:left" to your image tag to align it with the text side by side.

your HTML should become something like;

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="121">Download link</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://upload7.ir/up/icon-article-navy.png" alt="" width="20" height="20" class="dlboxicon"
                style="float: left;">[xfgiven_download]<a href="[xfvalue_download]"> [xfgiven_name] [xfvalue_name]
                [/xfgiven_name]
        </td>[/xfgiven_download]
        <a />
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Hope it helps!